# How to set default image in MVC Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I try this but not work

```
  @if (PortalContext.CurrentUser.ImageUrl != null)
  {
    <img src="@Url.Content(PortalContext.CurrentUser.ImageUrl)" alt="Picture" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;" />
  }
  else
  {
   //This Image show, when "PortalContext.CurrentUser.ImageUrl" image not view
   < img src="~/images/user-default-image.png" alt="Picture" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;" />
  }
```

If "PortalContext.CurrentUser.ImageUrl" content image path but anyhow image not preview then default image show. **How to do this?**

Comment: What do you mean  image not view ? is `ImageUrl ` equal to empty or `null`

Comment: My above code is work. But when ImageUrl  content image path but anyhow image not show  in that situation I want to show default image. How  to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Razor` Page :

> src="@(PortalContext.CurrentUser.ImageUrl == null ?
>   **Href**("~/assets/images/PhotoDefaultProfile.png")  : PortalContext.CurrentUser.ImageUrl